How Convert an object into Mono in reactive Programming
I am new to Reactive Programming in java. I tried to execute the below program in asynchronous way. I mean the main thread has to complete its execution without waiting for the Mono object. But the Main thread was blocked till the subscribe method completion. Can someone make this program asynchronous?
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Mono.just(getValue()).subscribe(value -> System.out.println(value));
}

public static int getValue() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return 10;
}

I tried to execute this program asynchronous and expecting this program will not wait for the Mono subcribe method should not execute and terminate immediately should not wait for 10 seconds.

In order to make call async you can create Mono.fromSupplier and afterwards subscribeOn a different scheduler, because by default subscription is made on main thread.
Mono.fromSupplier(()->getValue())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
.subscribe(value -> System.out.println(value));



It's because Mono.just() use eager computation rather than when it's subscribed to. That's the reason Mono.just() is not good for blocking operations.
The common use cases of Mono.just() is when you want to compute static or pre-compute values
You can try Mono.fromCallable(). It's basically lazy computation. The main thread will not wait for the getValue() function.
Here's the complete code that worked for me:
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class ReactiveProgJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main thread starts");

        Mono.fromCallable(() -> getValue())
                .subscribeOn(reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers.boundedElastic()) // Execute on a separate thread
                .subscribe(value -> System.out.println("Received: " + value));

        System.out.println("Returning to main thread"); // This will execute immediately
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(11000); // for sometime
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        System.out.println("printed after receiving");
    }

    public static int getValue() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); // Simulate a long-running task
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return 10;
    }
}

subscribeOn() is when the execution starts in a separate thread pool that you define. In the above example, Scheduler.boundedElastic() is when you want to offload the blocking operations to a thread pool.
You can check the documentation here: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#boundedElastic--
subscribe() is when you receive the output after blocking operation and you perform operation on that output.
Hope it helps!

I followed your suggestion but still main thread is waiting for getValue() completion.
Mono.fromCallable(() -> MonoTest.getValue()).subscribe(value -> System.out.println(value));

To offload a blocking operation to a thread pool, you need to use Scheduler.boundedElastic().
You can checkout the complete code in my solution. I've made some edits
